# Convert nvarchar to int results in error message

Tags: c#, sql-server

```
// https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/823002/How-to-clear-Request-Querystring

string url = context.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri; // Henter URL
string[] separateURL = url.Split('?'); // Splitter URL

NameValueCollection queryString = System.Web.HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(separateURL[0]); // Parameterne

string categoryId = queryString[0];  // Index 0 er categoryId

StringBuilder table = new StringBuilder();

con.Open();

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("uspPasteDataSubCategories", con);
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@categoryid", categoryId);

SqlDataReader rd = cmd.ExecuteReader();
```

I'm getting this error:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Error converting data type nvarchar to int.'

which doesn't make sense because the datatype is not `nvarchar` in the database.

Error happens at:

```
SqlDataReader rd = cmd.ExecuteReader();
```

Stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[uspPasteDataSubCategories]
    @categoryid INT
AS
    SELECT 
        SubCategory.subcategoryid, SubCategory.subcategoryname 
    FROM 
        Category, Category_SubCategory, SubCategory
    WHERE 
        Category.categoryid = @categoryid
        AND Category.categoryid = Category_SubCategory.categoryid
        AND SubCategory.subcategoryid = Category_SubCategory.subcategoryid
```

Comment: **SHOW US** the stored procedure and all the table structure involved

Comment: What type is categoryId in your stored proc?

Comment: I think `@categoryid` is expecting an `int`. Please confirm. If yes, try `int categoryId = int.Parse(queryString[0]);` and please keep in mind that `int.Parse` will cry if the value is not an integer and throw an exception.

Comment: [`AddWithValue`](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/) strikes again!

Comment: Stored Procedure added now, refresh

Comment: categoryID is clearly a string in your code. ADO can only guess at the datatype from what you pass in and seeing a string its best guess is NVarChar. First use the overload of the .Add method that requires the SqlDbType parameter. Second you can explicitly convert (not cast) your string to an int.

Comment: AddWithValue didn't strike. There was only a error in the Stored Procedure, it should be varchar, and not int.

Comment: But you still should not be using addwithvalue - a comment that has been made in your other questions. Learning much? And now your posted code doesn't match your description and comments. Assuming your procedure parameter is, in fact, defined as nvarchar, then the assumption should be that the column Category.CategoryID is numeric and that the value passed cannot be implicitly converted. You know what line causes the error - so what is the actual value of your local var CategoryId in your c# code?

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 25 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Answer (score 0):

```
// The stored procedure is expecting an int as the parameter type
string url = context.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri; // Henter URL
string[] separateURL = url.Split('?'); // Splitter URL

NameValueCollection queryString = System.Web.HttpUtility.ParseQueryString    (separateURL[0]); // Parameterne

string strCategoryId = queryString[0];  // Index 0 er categoryId

StringBuilder table = new StringBuilder();

con.Open();

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("uspPasteDataSubCategories", con);
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
//Convert the string value to int
int categoryId = Int32.Parse(strCategoryId);

//Changed to use add verse AddWithValue. This way you can set the type for the parameter. Then you can set the value.
cmd.Parameters.Add("@categoryid", SqlDbType.Int);
cmd.Parameters["@categoryid"].Value = categoryId;

SqlDataReader rd = cmd.ExecuteReader();
```

Comment: System.FormatException: 'The input string had invalid format.'

Comment: ensure that your queryString[0]; is retrieving a valid integer.

Comment: It is, I previously used string to have it added in the URI

Comment: This code block is not a good answer as it lacks any explanation.

Comment: It would be a better if you explained how your answer solves the question, rather just posting code

Comment: Added additional comments to explain what I had changed and why.